# Change the user is logged in cookie name

Tags: cookies

I have menu items that are set to be shown/hidden depending on if the user is logged in. I would like to change the default cookie name that WP looks for to determine login status.

My cookie name is `_example` and has a value of `1` when user is logged in.

I have tried `define( 'TEST_COOKIE', '_example' );` in `wp-config.php`, but that didn't seem to do the trick.

How can I replace the default cookie name?

Note: I do not need to identify which user is logged in, only whether or not it is true to show/hide menu items. `_example` has a value of `1` if logged in, otherwise `_example` is not present or `0`.

Comment: What does the cookie name have to do with hiding/showing menu items if the user's logged in? WordPress has functions for that sort of check that doesn't require hard-coding a single specific cookie name.

Comment: Because I am using an external site (subdomain) where the user logs in. They aren't using the WP login.

Comment: That doesn't mean you have to change the cookie name, and it's not how most SSO works either

Comment: I have to change the name so that WP can identify logged in status and show/hide menu items.

Comment: to use an external authentication system, it's better to use this filter https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/authenticate/

Comment: I don't necessarily need to hook the authentication. The user uses a Login link to the subdomain login (non-WP). He logs in a returns to the WP site and has the cookie set to 1. Now the WP site should show different menu items (hide Login menu item, show Logout menu item). I am not using the WP side to show any user data, not even user ID. The cookie is simply used for showing/hiding menu items. If the standard Menu option for logged in/out visibility can't be used, I can just write a JS function to show/hide classes or IDs based on cookie state, but I thought it might be easier than that.

Answer (score 1):

Cookies do not indicate login status. Even if the cookie is not expired it is possible to terminate the session on admin side, and obviously, just the fact that there is a cookie do not mean that the information in it will authenticate. Sounds like you need an actual SSO solution.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try? This is the answer of how to change logged in cookie name :)

```
define( 'COOKIEHASH',           md5( 'http://example.tld' )    ); 
define( 'LOGGED_IN_COOKIE',     'wpse_logged_in_' . COOKIEHASH );
```

Comment: Please **[edit] your answer**, and add an explanation: **why** could that solve the problem?